# use a function as function argument to use in with statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

in certain softwares, I have to use a lot the 'with statement' to create a certain context before run some functions (it's not changeable, I have to fit this way of doing it)

So I made a function with the needed 'with statement', to use it in a more simple way with many subfunctions later :

```
def getContext(subfunction):
    context=... #creating the context here
    with context:
        return subfunction

something = getContext( var.getValue() )
```

It return an error in my softwares, as it's run the subfunction in argument before passing it to the 'getContext' function.

I've so I tried :

```
def whatValue(var):
    return var.getValue()

def getContext(subfunction):
    context=... #creating the context here
    with context:
        return subfunction
something = getContext( whatValue( var ) )
```

I gives the exact same error as the first try. so my question is :

how can I pass a subfunction as an argument and make the subfunction runs only in the context function ?

EDIT : to clarify, yes I'm talking about send the function itself, not the result

thank you

Comment: You are *passing the result of calling the function*, so of course it is running first. You mean to `getContext( var.getValue )` and then I think `getContext` should `return subfunction()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you mean to send the function itself, and so you need to let the context wrapper call it. Making it a bit more general to handler an arbitrary amount of arguments:

```
def getContext(subfunction, *args, **kwargs):
    context=... #creating the context here
    with context:
        return subfunction(*args, **kwargs)

something = getContext( var.getValue )  # Can add arguments and named arguments.
```

Note I pass `getValue` rather then `getValue()`, and `getContext` itself makes the call.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. It also gives me a hint to learn the *args and **kwargs things
thank you !

Answer (score 1):

When you write `function_name(...)`, function name will always be executed at this point in time.  If you just want to pass the function, you just write `function_name`.  I.e., in your example:

```
something = getContext(var.getValue)
```

or in the version with `whatValue` (although that is an unnecessary indirection):

```
something = getContext(whatValue)
```

However, I am note sure this solves your context problem.  Because within the context `context` you return the function itself but the context is then not used by the function being returned, because the context ends when the corresponding block ends.

Comment: thanks Tom, kabanus answer is on the same path and allow it to work as expected